# Why is my data usage high when all devices and wifi are off?

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet-connection

On my home internet my downloads are typically 0 to 1Gb per day and have been for years. About a month ago they jumped to about 6Gb per day, despite no change to my usage patterns, devices or modem.

For diagnostic purposes I switched off the modem and saw usage drop to zero for the approximately 12 hours until I switched it back on.

On a separate occasion I ran a different diagnostic test when the modem was on, but I unplugged all the output ethernet cables and turned off the wifi, so no devices were capable of getting internet, but the recorded usage was still 6Gb or so. I triple checked everything and all ethernet cables were definitely all unplugged, and wifi was definitely off (my phone couldn't connect to wifi in this period). This suggests I can definitively rule out my own usage as a contributing factor.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this excessive usage? Or suggest some other diagnostics I can run? If it's relevant, I'm in Australia on NBN and my provider is Internode. I've already called them about this and they are sending a techie out, but otherwise don't know either.

Update: this issue was resolved by replacing the modem. Usage is back down to normal levels and has remained so for several consecutive days. It is unclear what the original issue was that caused such high downloads even when no devices were connected and wifi was off, but for now it is no longer present.

Comment: Is there anything to solve here? I also have quite some traffic every day, probably mostly port scans and VoIP keep-alives.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have 6GB usage when nothing is connected to the modem? Where do you see it? Have you tried to reboot the modem, or even to factory-reset it (beware as this will erase of settings)?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, that's correct. Literally nothing is connected to the modem, but there is 6GB of usage. I see it by logging into my account with the internet provider, which shows a breakdown of my daily usage. Until a month ago, my usage was always 1GB or less. Then it suddenly jumped and was consistently 6GB per day.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried turning the modem off and on, and the issue stops while the modem is off, but starts up again when I turn it back on. I have not tried a factory reset of the modem.

Comment: @DanielB Is 6GB worth of port scans plausible? Even when nothing is connected, not even the VoIP phone? For years the usage has been under 1GB a day. Now it's over 6GB, even when nothing is connected, which adds up to nearly 200GB in a month.

Comment: Did your ISP switch you to wireless TV?

Comment: @John I don't believe so. Nothing has been mentioned to us, and we can still watch tv just fine with the ethernet cables unplugged and wireless off, or the modem off.

Comment: So you do not have wireless TV and all your devices and wireless are truly OFF?  Did you contact your ISP?

Comment: @John Yes to both. Phoned the ISP and they say everything is fine at their end, and they'll send out a technician.

Comment: Update: factory reset of modem did not help. Technician has come out to take a look. Says he's never seen anything like this before. We're going to try replacing the modem to see if that helps. Will report back when that's happened.

Comment: This is the second question like this that I've seen in the last month. I wonder if it's going to turn out that someone has a way of turning some cable modems into botnet bots. But I suppose Occam's razor makes it more likely to just be a bug. @lilu Do you know the exact make and model of the modem that had the problem (not the replacement)? It could be a valuable data point for future sleuths.